# Submenu items not showing anymore on the navigation

Tags: menus

My submenu disappeared all the sudden and doesn't show anymore when I hover over the menu item. I checked the menu section on my WP dashboard and it's there and assigned to show. The submenu still show on mobile device but on full browser the submenu items stopped showing up. I deactivated all the plugins to check if there is a conflict but the event doesn't appear to be plugin related.

Here's my website: http://www.apcm.ca , menu set up below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what happened before you lost your subnav, I'll walk you through troubleshooting.

First, look at your code.

I viewed your code with Developer Tools (in most browesers press `F12`) and found your submenu is there. Which means it is likely a missing javascript file or CSS issue.

Retrace your steps.

Is there a change to your theme?

I looked at your CSS from your theme ( http://www.apcm.ca/wp-content/themes/apcm/css/style.css?ver=4.6.1 ) and found the code to hide `subnav` and reveal when the parent `li` is hovered over.

SO,

I went back to Developer Tools and navigated down to a `ul  class="subnav"`and unckecked the different values for `subnav`

then I saw your submenu popped up when `top: 100%` was unchecked.

THEREFORE

That code is your culprit.

Recommendation: this is not a Wordpress issue, but a CSS issue. Post this on stackoverflow for a response.